# Run .vbs file on floppy with autorun.inf

Tags: vbscript, autorun, floppy

So I have a 1.44MB floppy disk that has a .vbs file named `autorun.vbs`. I also have a `autorun.inf` file on the root of it. The `autorun.inf` looks like this:

```
[autorun]
open = autorun.vbs
```

Nothing happens. I tried putting the floppy into my new Vista computer, but nothing happens (the script opens a `MsgBox`). What should I add to `autorun.inf`?

Yes, I know MS got rid of AutoPlay in 7 and made a update for Vista, but I did not connect to the Internet and I'm using Vista SP2.